# How should "knowledgeability" be defined? Is it merely w.r.t. to best scientific knowledge?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, knowledge, education

How should "knowledgeability" be defined?

Is it merely w.r.t. to best scientific knowledge? What about things that science cannot measure?

Or are there other "reasonable" forms of knowledge? Why are they "reasonable"?

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C10&q=knowledgeability&btnG= Googling knowledgeability on Scholar brings up several academic papers that use the term. You might like to start there.

Comment: I think this is certainly philosophical question.

Comment: It may be, however I haven't been able to find anything on it in the usual philosophical literature. There is no mention of it in etymology either. It seems to be a term coined and used by the government, CIA, and a few educational researchers. It would be nice if you could provide us with an instance of the word used in philosophical literature. That would give us something to work with. Otherwise, I think this question is more suitable for the English Language and Usage SE.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/texts?and%5B%5D=knowledgeability&sin=

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C10&q=knowledgeability+in+philosophy&btnG= googled "knowledgeability in philosophy", shows papers on the subject of teaching philosophy to children.

Comment: @Bread But my question is not about "in context of philosophical literature". But in context of science or phil. of science. I'm looking for possibly "the most reliable definition for 'being knowledgeable'".

Comment: It appears to be technical jargon related to either Government Intelligence and/or Education, rather than anything even remotely philosophical.

Comment: Knowledgeability as it is actually used historically is in context to some characteristic of information. The knowledgeability of classified information meant basically how many people and specifically which people could have access to it. The knowledgeability of subject matter within a curriculum means the ease with which students might be capable of comprehension.

Comment: @Bread https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology

Answer (score 3):

Well, mavavilj, definitions are easy - dictionaries are teeming with them. None of them is right or wrong, they're only more or less agreeable to whomever interprets them!

However, 'knowledge' isn't a scientific term, it's a philosophical issue. Science is more concerned with evidence, *theory* and statistical analysis.

Are you keeping in mind the contemporary (*postmodern*) approach to the limits of human comprehension? Karl Popper acknowledged (in his 1972 book *Objective Knowledge: an Evolutionary Approach*, p. 75) that the inductive inferences (objective knowledge) which science generates should not be regarded as "true" claims, writing, "...there simply are no sufficient reasons for holding those hypotheses to be true, let alone certainly true.”

Maybe this will clarify what you're asking(?):  Popper also proposed that two different  kinds of knowledge exist: conscious experiential (subjective) *understandings* (one's beliefs, opinions and theories) and abstract linguistic sets of ideas ( "*objective*") knowledge). Neither type is noted for *consistency*, although scientists and philosophers should certainly focus on *coherency*!

Comment: weird answer, but i upvoted it, thanks

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that; language and knowledge do appear weird sometimes...paradox, ambiguity, interpretation...what a mess!